# Position a TextView on top of a Google Map

Tags: c#, layout, textview, position, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin Google Maps application and am wanting to position a TextView at the top of my application and in the center.

I have done some research and I see that I should not use an absolute layout.

How is the best way to do this? Should I use a layout? Will this easily work on top of my Google Map?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative layout to hold the map view and the textview and then set the text views `android:layout_centerInParent` and `android:layout_alignParentTop` attribute to `true`:

```
...
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <TextView
       android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout/>
...
```

Note that this could interfere with the usability of the map view due to the textview overlapping it.